# What are the origins of the Master Sword?

Tags: legend-of-zelda-series

Have the origins of the Master Sword ever been explained?

As far as I know, every Legend of Zelda game features the same Master Sword, passed down through the generations. However, even in Skyward Sword, the Master Sword already exists (you have to power it up, but the sword is already there).

Was it forged? Did it just pop into existance when one of the godesses created it? What are the origins of the Master Sword?

Comment: Why has this been down voted so many times

Comment: @Panomosh There are some people in this community who have a strict aversion to Lore questions.

Comment: Really I don't get those who are anti lore questions. Yes it's more open ended than mechanics questions, but there are a lot of interesting details in the Lore that might change a lot of how we understand a game.

Comment: It's not just because it's a lore question. I suspect this is downvoted because there's an entire Zelda game dedicated to the origin story for the Master Sword (Skyward Sword).

Comment: But still, in that game the Sword is whole. It is why it has the power to repeal ganon, but Fi was already in the sword and well, it was already a relic. If it was just randomly Link's sword that was powered up, there wouldn't be a question; but the sword seems to already have a story behind it, predating the Skyward Sword story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [wiki page on the Master Sword](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Master_Sword):

> **Originally crafted by the goddess Hylia as the Goddess Sword, it was later forged into the Master Sword by the Goddess's chosen hero and its spirit, Fi**, who bathed it in the three Sacred Flames located across the land that would become the Kingdom of Hyrule. Din's Flame in particular imbued the sword with the Power to Repel Evil, a power augmented after the Sword received the blessing of Zelda, which transformed the blade into the True Master Sword.

The wiki page goes much more in depth about the origin of the Master Sword further in the article. The explanation is much too long to put into an answer, however,  so I've only included the summary of its creation.